# Trying to figure out exercise from How to Think Like Computer Scientist Learning With Python Three with Turtle Module, receiving NameError

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to work out the first exercise from *How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3, chapter 4*.
I am attempting to learn how to integrate functions into code using the `turtle` module. When I try to run the code below, I receive the following error at line 8:

```
"NameError: name 't' is not defined"
```

How do I fix this?

```
import turtle

def square_array(t, sz):
    """
    Have turtle t make a square.
    """
for i in range (3):
  t.forward(sz)
  t.left(90)

wn= turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
wn.title("Alex makes some squares dawg")

alex=turtle.Turtle
alex.pensize(5)
alex.color("red")

for i in range (4):
    square_array(alex, 20)
    alex.forward(20)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: If this is accurate indentation, then your indentation is wrong, at least the first `for` loop should be indented. `t` is introduce in the `square_array` arg list.

Answer (score 3):

Just change your indentation:

```
def square_array(t, sz):
    """
    Have turtle t make a square.
    """
    for i in range(3):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(90)
```

And you need to actually call `Turtle` to initialise it:

```
alex = turtle.Turtle()
```